# SQLite3 - Complex WHERE expression that uses two tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite, where-clause

*Sorry for my English*

I have two tables:

**Partners**

```
ID | NAME | IS_FAVORITE
```

**PartnerPoints**

```
ID | PARTNER_ID | NAME
```

And I want to get all rows from `PartnerPoints` which related to `Partners` (by `PARTNER_ID`) with the field `IS_FAVORITE` set to `1`. I.e. I want to get all *favorite* partner points.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use  a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT PartnerPoints.*
  FROM PartnerPoints
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT *
                  FROM Partners
                 WHERE Partners.ID = PartnerPoints.PARTNER_ID
                   AND Partners.IS_FAVORITE = 1
              )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by **JOINING** the tables.

```
SELECT PartnerPoints.*
FROM PartnerPoints JOIN Partners ON PartnerPoints.Partner_ID=Partners.ID
WHERE Partners.Is_favorite = 1
```

This is an **INNER JOIN**. Oscar Pérez’s answer, with the subquery, is called a **SEMI-JOIN**. The database may execute the same plan, or this INNER JOIN may be faster. In more complicated cases, you may have to use a semi-join.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by first computing the IDs of all favorite partners, and then searching for PartnerPoints that have such a partner ID:

```
SELECT *
FROM PartnerPoints
WHERE Partner_ID IN (SELECT ID
                     FROM Partners
                     WHERE Is_Favorite = 1)
```

Which type of query is fastest depends on the amount and distribution of data in the tables, and of which indexes you have; if the speed actually matters to you, you have to measure all three queries.